# Callkit incoming call UI hides in background

Tags: swift, voip, callkit

I am developing one VoIP based application with the user of callkit.
I am facing one issue which is sometimes incoming call UI goes in Background i.e. I am able to hear ringtone and when I double click the home button the callkit UI is there in background

I am using these method to handle new incoming calls

```swift
private func reportIncomingCall(uuid: UUID, 
handle: String, callerName: String, isVideo: Bool, completion: ((Error?)->(Void))? = nil) {
    let callUpdate = CXCallUpdate()
    callUpdate.hasVideo = isVideo

    callUpdate.localizedCallerName = callerName
    callUpdate.remoteHandle = CXHandle(type: .phoneNumber, value: handle)

    provider.reportNewIncomingCall(with: uuid, update: callUpdate){ (error) in

        print("New Call reported")

        if error == nil {
            let call = Call(uuid: uuid, handle: handle, callName: callerName, date: Date())
            AppDelegate.shared.callManager.add(call: call)
        }
        completion?(error)            
    }
}
```